# Pass angular object property to ngDialog open()?

Tags: angularjs, parameters, ng-dialog

Is there a way to pass an angular object property to ngDialog modal window? It seems you cannot pass it like you can in normal html:

`<img ng-src="{{ member.picture }}" alt="{{ member.name }}" ng-click="showModal(' member.id ')" /><br />`

In the above, the first two object properties (`member.picture` and `member.name`) work normally and gets replaced with the actual content in the view, for example `path/to/picture.jpg` and `Juha Untinen`, but the third one is passed as a string literal to `showModal()`.

How can I pass the actual contents of `member.id`, which has a numeric value like 1, 2, or 3? So that the final parameter would be for example: `showModal(1)`

If I do this:
`ng-click="showModal( {{ member.id }} )"`, I get this error:

`Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 13 of the expression [showModal( {{ member.id }} )] starting at [{ member.id }} )].`

Here's the ngDialog function in the controller:

```
$scope.showModal = function(param) {
    ngDialog.open({
        template: 'app/biography/bioModal' + param + ".html",
        className: 'ngdialog-theme-plain',
        showClose: true,
        scope: $scope
    });
};
```

That is for testing passing the parameter. In the final version, I hope to have one partial view, which has the details (name, picture, etc) filled depending on the id parameter passed to it.

Comment: you have to pass the parameter without quotes as ng-click="showModal(member.id)"

Comment: Ah, awesome! The only thing I didn't try heh. That works, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass a string as parameter, so member.id will not get resolved.

What you to do is to pass the parameter without quotes as

```
ng-click="showModal(member.id)"
```

Comment: This one works. I cannot accept it as the answer yet, it says I need to wait for 5 minutes more :)